# In gradle, can I compile a local module and use that as dependencies for other 'external' libraries?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jcenter

I'm using a fork of Exoplayer in my project which I included as a git submodule and compile along my other modules:

```
compile project(':libraries:exoplayer:library')
```

Now I'm trying to link with an external SDK that has an explicit dependency to exoplayer in its pom file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android.exoplayer</groupId>
  <artifactId>exoplayer</artifactId>
  <version>r1.4.2</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

How can I tell gradle to use the fork of exoplayer and not the jcenter one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can ignore the transitive dependency like this:

```
dependencies{
  compile('your:external:sdk') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.exoplayer', module: 'exoplayer'
  }
}
```